# Usar Hibernate para gravar duas classes iguais

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de relacionar a classe `Partida` com a classe `Time`, onde partida receberia a PK(Id) do time de casa e do time visitante. Estou com dúvidas de como relacionar em ambas as classes, pois utilizar na classe `Partida`, conforme abaixo:

```
@ManyToOne
private List<Time> times;
```

Me parece incorreto.

Como eu poderia relacionar ambas as classes e gerar as tabelas no banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia transformar o mapeamento de suas classes da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="time")
public class Time  {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "time_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "time_nome")
    private String nome;
```

Já na classe Partida, você teria o relacionamento com os dois times, o da casa e o de fora.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="partida")
public class Partida 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "partida_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "time_casa_fk")
    private Time timeCasa;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "time_fora_fk")
    private Time timeFora;
```

Para complementar, para que os 2 times não sejam iguais em uma mesma partida, você pode colocar uma chave de restrição.

Comment: No caso não é necessário adicionar a anotação de @OneToMany na classe Time?

Comment: Do jeito que mostrei acima, o relacionamento já realizado